# Scrollbar doesn't work with max-height on parent

Tags: css

I have a parent container that have a `max-height` value, and a children div with a `height: 100%;` and an `overflow: auto;`, and I need that the children get a scrollbar (and not the container) relative to the height of the parent container.

It's working when I try to put `height` property on the container parent, but I doesn't understand why it's not working with the `max-height` property.

Here an exemple of that I don't want (but working) with `height` property
https://jsfiddle.net/pwjs2dmc/2/

Here an exemple of that I want (not working) with `max-height` property
https://jsfiddle.net/pwjs2dmc/1/

Have you an idea of the problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played with it you need to give max height to child so the overflow is actually applicable.

This works for me

```
.container
{
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:cyan;
}
.container .content
{
  max-height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

And you were giving 100%  height to child which means it will always take up all the height and always ignore overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try this way.

Answer (score 1):

Replaced `overflow:hidden` form parent to `overflow-y: auto` and remove overflow form child

```css
.container
{
  position:relative;
  max-height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  background:cyan;
}
.container .content
{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it will work too but in my case I wanted to have the scollbar on the .content div

Comment: oh ok then add scroll auto and max height on .content